# Renaming :search params of MetaSearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-search

I'm working on rails 3.1.1 and ree-1.8.7 with meta_search 1.1.1 gem.

I would like to know if there is any way to rename the :search param of MetaSearch :

the controller:

```
User.metasearch(params[:search])
```

the search form view:

```
= form_for @users_search, :url => users_path, :html => {:method => :get} do |f|
  = f.label :name_contains
  = f.text_field :name_contains
  = f.submit
```

I need to do this because it interferes with another text field of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an "as" option you can pass.

```
form_for @users_search, :as => 'q', :url => users_path, :html => {:method => :get} do |f|
```

Check out [form_for documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) for more details.